# Method of solving $w''(y) - (1+y^2)w(y) = y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have not done ode's for awhile and have forgotten a lot of stuff.

What method am I supposed to use to solve this  $w''(y) - (1+y^2)w(y) = y$  (please don't solve it for me). I guess I can use series to solve it but there should be some other method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you find any useful expressions for the solutions. [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) says that the solutions of your equation are expressed in terms of [parabolic cylinder functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicCylinderFunction.html), which are *defined* as a solution of a differential equation which is very similar to yours.

Comment: What about the homogeneous equation? Do you know which method might work? I have forgotten a lot of stuff

Comment: Same story with the homogenous equation. The solution looks simplier, yet it still requires parabolic cylinder functions. `http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DSolve[w%27%27%3D%3D%281%2By^2%29+w%2C+w%2Cy]`